# Signing a Java Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, signed-applet

I have signed a Java Applet jar using Verisign certificate.

When Java Applet is run from a html/javascript , a dialog box appears which asks whether the unknown certicate needs to be trusted or not & the Java Application should be run or not. When clicked on Run button(indicating Agreed) & checking(ticked on) the checkbox which indicates that the user is not asked everytime , the Java Applet window is displayed.

Kindly confirm whether even after signing the Java Applet with a certificate which belongs to a trusted thirty party Certifying Authority(CA) like Verisign , the first alert dialog asking for confirmation whether to run the untrusted Java application is normally asked or not.

Comment: PS Out of curiosity, why is your applet signed? From what I can see, these days there isn't much need for signed applets given all the native capabilities of modern browsers. The main exceptions I can think of are bulk file upload, and live media like anything that would use the user's camera or microphone.

Comment: its very clearly stated in the very first line of the question , "I have signed a Java Applet jar using Verisign certificate."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the browser's configuration. Unless the signer of the certificate is one which the browser has already been configured to accept automatically, the user will still be prompted to accept the certificate at least once.

Remember, your code is asking permission to perform privileged actions on the user's machine. Just because your **identity** has been verified by a trusted third party, doesn't mean that the user must automatically trust your **code**.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Dan's answer: Yes, it will always ask the user the first time. This is the default configuration of the Java plug-in. The configuration could be changed, but that would be a very bad practice.

Comment: By "configuration" I also meant the common practice in institutional IT departments of preloading the browser with certain "authors" as automatically trusted.

Comment: @Sarel Botha according to your answer how we chnage configuration of JRE plug in so it would not ask for user permission. can we do it programatically or manually ?

Comment: Look in the java control panel. I don't know if you can turn off the prompts off completely with the latest JRE. On a 64-bit machine use this command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe -viewer`. You can probably programmatically do this by editing files in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment